# Checking specific checkboxes based on select option using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check checkboxes based on a select option. So, if the user chooses one option 3 from the dropdown, I want it to automatically check checkboxes with the ids set as 4, 24, and 17.

I have predefined the variables using PHP, so that my array is as follows:

```
var per =[]; 

per['3'] = []; 
per['3']['4'] = '4'; 
per['3']['24'] = '24'; 
per['3']['17'] = '17'; 

per['4'] = []; 
per['4']['null'] = 'null'; 

per['6'] = []; 
per['6']['19'] = '19';
```

The array is setup so that per[‘VALUE’] is the option for the select. (The user selects 3 and tickboxes 4, 24, & 17 are checked).

I have managed to use an alert to test that I can pull out the right data. I think it may be something in my reference to the checkbox that is killing me.

My jquery code:

```
    $("#get_boxes").change(function () {
    var per =[]; 

per['3'] = []; 
per['3']['4'] = '4'; 
per['3']['24'] = '24'; 
per['3']['17'] = '17'; 

per['4'] = []; 
per['4']['null'] = 'null'; 

per['6'] = []; 
per['6']['19'] = '19';

    var role = $(this).val();
        $.each(per[role], function(k, v){
            if(v != undefined) { 
            $('#'+v).attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

The html:

```
<select name="role" id="get_boxes" class="full-width">
    <option value="null">---</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
<option value="6">Six</option>
</select>
<p class="halflist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="permission[1]" id="1" />
        <label for="1" class="inline">Tick One</label>
</p><p class="halflist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="permission[4]" id="4" />
        <label for="4" class="inline">Tick Four</label>
</p><p class="halflist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="permission[5]" id="5" />
        <label for="5" class="inline">Tick Five</label>
</p><p class="halflist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="permission[6]" id="6" />
        <label for="6" class="inline">Tick Six</label>
</p><p class="halflist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="permission[2]" id="2" />
        <label for="2" class="inline">Tick Two</label>
</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you want something like this

```
var ar = ['Odd','Even'];
ar['Odd'] = [1,3,5,7,9];
ar['Even'] = [0,2,4,6,8];
$('select').change(function() {
    var t = $(this).val();
    $.each(ar[t], function(key,value) {
        $('#'+value).attr('checked',true);
    });
});​
```

Obviously this is a different context, but you can easily replace the values for what you want to replace.

### Here's a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sUHNp/

Comment: I don't understand how it was different from what I had (I compared line by line) but it's working now! :)  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off adding classes to the dependent checkboxes. For example, if a person checks checkbox A and then checkboxes B, C, and D are supposed to be automatically checked, you can add a class of check_A to checkboxes B, C, and D. Then you just need to do a jQuery select on .check_A.

HTML...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="A" />
<input type="checkbox" id="B" class="check_A" />
<input type="checkbox" id="C" class="check_A" />
<input type="checkbox" id="D" class="check_A" />
<input type="checkbox" id="E" />
<input type="checkbox" id="F" class="check_E" />
<input type="checkbox" id="G" class="check_E" />
<input type="checkbox" id="H" class="check_E" />
```

Javascript...

```
$('#A').change(function() {
    $('.check_A').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Comment: I can't work it that way. The list of which ones come checked are dynamic and based on another set of settings. Imagine it like user roles and the check boxes are individual permissions. The select will be a previously created role that they can base the settings on - basically a dupe function. also, checkbox #D may be part of multiple select options. Won't quite work for me, but thanks! :)